# How to determine whether a linked list contains a loop?

Tags: linked-list

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [find whether a loop in a linked list without two pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338683/find-whether-a-loop-in-a-linked-list-without-two-pointers)
>   [How to determine if a linked list has a cycle using only two memory locations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494830/how-to-determine-if-a-linked-list-has-a-cycle-using-only-two-memory-locations)
>   [Best algorithm to test if a linked list has a cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249/best-algorithm-to-test-if-a-linked-list-has-a-cycle)

During a preparation for a job interview, I encountered the following question:

How can you determine whether a linked list (of any type) contains a loop, using additional space complexity of O(1)? You cannot assume that the loop starts at the first node (and of course, the loop doesn't have to contain all nodes).

I couldn't find the answer, though I have the feeling it's quite simple...

Comment: I missed this exact question on an interview myself. I was only able to give the O(*n*) memory & time solution.

Comment: I learned about this in a CS class, but I don't think it's a particularly good question since it's "only obvious if you already know".

Comment: Many, many duplicates, e.g. [find whether a loop in a linked list without two pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338683/find-whether-a-loop-in-a-linked-list-without-two-pointers)

Comment: Danny posted a good answer below -- if you want some search terms to learn more about it, try "Floyd's cycle detection algorithm" or "tortoise and hare algorithm".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy. Maintain two pointers into the list. At each step, advance one pointer by a single link, and advance the other by two links. Test to see if they point to the same element. If so, you have a loop. If not, repeat until you find a loop or you reach the end of the list.

Comment: I found that this solution was only "easy" if you knew it. This is, in my opinion, quite clever thinking.

Comment: Interesting. Why bother advancing the other at all?

Comment: Any link may be equal to any other link, so they must both move around the list to test every (reachable) combination.

Comment: @T.E.D: The first node of the list may not be part of the cycle.  IFF a cycle exists, there will be some i such that X_i = X_2*i, and the tortoise and hare algorithm finds the smallest such i if it exists.

Comment: Ahhhh. Thank you. The name sounds familiar, but my CS algorithms class was more than 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the same technique as checking if a graph is a tree (trees don't get to have cycles), see [this this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583876/how-do-i-check-if-a-directed-graph-is-acyclic).  It recommends either a topological sort or a depth first search.

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact problem in real live code last week.

All I did was kept a pointer (link) for the first element. Then as I iterated through the list, if I ever got that pointer again, I know there's a loop.

Comment: See the comments on the accepted answer for why this won't catch *all* cycles, and why that is a better solution.

Comment: The loop does not necessarily start at the first element.